# jQuery append() and data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have unknown number of divs with increasing ID's:

```
<div id="source-1" data-grab="someURL"/>Content</div>
<div id="source-2" data-grab="anotherURL"/>Content</div>
<div id="source-3" data-grab="anddifferentURL"/>Content</div>
<div id="source-4" data-grab="andthelastoneURL"/>Content</div>
```

And I have another list:

```
<ul>
   <li id="target-1" class="target"><a href="#"> </a></li>
   <li id="target-2" class="target"><a href="#"> </a></li>
   <li id="target-3" class="target"><a href="#"> </a></li>
   <li id="target-4" class="target"><a href="#"> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, what I want to achive is grabbing data-grab URL from source-1 and append it to target-1 as a image and so forth. So finally the output list will look just like:

```
<ul>
       <li id="target-1"><a href="#"><img src="someURL" /> </a></li>
       <li id="target-2"><a href="#"><img src="anotherURL" /> </a></li>
       <li id="target-3"><a href="#"><img src="anddifferentURL" /> </a></li>
       <li id="target-4"><a href="#"><img src="andthelastoneURL" /> </a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm grabbing all the data from the first list, but I'm not sure how to append right source element to right target element?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.target').each(function(){
                var URL = jQuery(this).data('grab');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.target').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var divID = "source-" + ($this.id()).split("-")[1];
     $("a", $this).append('<img src="' + $(divID).data("grab") + '" />');
  });
});
```

Comment: why there's var $this not "var this"? :) I'm working on my script and going to say if it works, but I'm sure it will!

Comment: @Wordpressor using var $this = $(this) cuts down on the jquery selector call and makes the code slightly more efficient than constantly using $(this) everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't divID equate to "source1" and not "source-1"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use indices to select the right elements, if you add a class to your source elements (like `.source`):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                var targets = $( '.target' );
                $('.source').each(function(index, value){
                    $(target[index]).children("a").first().append($("<img src=" + value.data('grab') + " />"));
                });
            });
```